# Visual Studio Code stopped using certain built-in features

Tags: tags, highlight, matching

I am a fresh student for fullstack Web Development.

so far I have used VScode to write css, html and javascript.

yesterday i noticed that a lot of built-in features in vscode suddenly stopped working.

for example, vscode won't autocomplete code lines, it won't highlight matching tags, it stopped previewing css colors in the little box near the color code lines.

to make it short, it became a bit more like notepad than vscode

could this be due to a recent update issue or did i do something to cause that?

I already tried deleting VScode, including the folders that perserve settings which will not delete after uninstalling.

did this ever happen to you?
what can i do to fix this?

thanks in advance,
-Julian

Comment: What language mode does it show on the bottom?

Comment: it shows HTML as the language

Comment: although i usually use javascript and css in the html files without seperating them.
i have just noticed that if i do seperate them, the css files shows the colors.
the html file though still does not highlight matching tags.